Build MSIX project for Class Library in VS2022
I'm trying to add reference to an Class Library project from MSIX project in VS2022.
I always receive the following error message:
"referenced project paths must contain at least one element.
Parameter name: referencedProjectPaths"

If I add WinForm then it accepts it, but with Class Library (dll) it doesn't go.
I need to refernce the dll only and there is no intention to create a dummy exe to get it done.
I tried to modify the .wapproj project file but I don't have a clue how can I manually add the reference to the class library project and related tags.

The .wapproj is for installing applications. MSIX doesn't really install class libraries.

Thanks Rob.
So, in such case, how can I bundle the dll as msi for deployment from VS2022 or Azure DevOps Build pipelines?

Use the WiX Toolset https://wixtoolset.org
